# WiX: properly delete non-empty temp files and folders on Uninstall

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

Before I get started, let me note, that I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940364/wix-how-to-delete-non-empty-folder) [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492769/wix-remove-old-program-folder-before-install) all related questions here, on SO, and found no solution. So the question aims the same problem as many before did:

> How to properly delete temp folders and misc files that are being created while an application works using WiX facilities?

So far I came up with the following ways to do this:

1. Using **CustomAction** (written, for example, in C#) that will simply delete all files and folders (this works great, but this workaround seems to me not valid as there is no support for **Rollback** from MSI side).
2. Using **util:RemoveFolderEx** tag from **WixUtilExtension**. I could't make this work.
3. Using **CustomAction** (written, again, in C#)  that will populate MSI DB's tables (**Directory** and **RemoveFile**) just before UnInstall happens. This will force MSI to properly and in its own way uninstall all enumerated files and folders (in theory it should do this) via **RemoveFiles** default action.

**I have focused on the third way and asking you a bit of a help here.**

**Few notes about application layout**
MSI that I built works great with *ProgramFiles*, *Shortcuts*, *Registry* and all that stuff. But during installation I put some configuration files into `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\` folder (they are being removed too w/o any issues).

But while the application works it produces additional files and dirs in `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\`, that is used to update the app once new release is available. Let's assume the user closes the application in the middle of the update process and wants to uninstall the application. Here is what we have at the moment in the `C:\ProgramData\MyApp` folder:

> C:\ProgramData\MyApp\
>   C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\
>   C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\tool.exe
>   C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\somelib.dll
>   C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\<UniqueFolderNameBasedOnGUID>\someliba.dll
>   C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\<UniqueFolderNameBasedOnGUID<\somelibb.dll

At the end of the uninstalation procedure I want to see no `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\` folder. And I **can** see this if no temp dirs/files are being created.

Please note, I do not know the name of folders and files being put in `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\` folder as the final folder name is generated automatically using GUID.

Let me focus on the most important parts of the project and show you what I have done so far in order to accomplish the task (please, remember, I picked the 3rd way: via **CustomAction**):

**`Main MyApp.wxs file`**

```
<Product Id=...>
  ...
  <!-- Defines a DLL contains the RemoveUpdatesAction function -->
  <Binary Id="RemoveUpdatesAction.CA.dll" src="RemoveUpdatesAction.CA.dll" />
  <CustomAction Id="RemoveUpdatesAction" 
                Return="check" 
                Execute="immediate" 
                BinaryKey="RemoveUpdatesAction.CA.dll" 
                DllEntry="RemoveUpdatesAction" />
  ...
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- Perform custom CleanUp only on 'UnInstall' action - see condition -->
    <Custom Action='RemoveUpdatesAction' Before='RemoveFiles'>
        (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")    
    </Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
  ...
</Product>
```

And later in the file, I define the **`Folder Layout`** for **ProgramData** directory:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    ....
    <!-- ...\Program Files\MyApp\ -->
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="APPINSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp" />
    </Directory>

    ....

    <!-- This is it! ...\ProgramData\MyApp\ -->
    <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
      <Directory Id="SETTINGSINSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp" />
    </Directory>
    ....
  </Directory>
</Fragment>

... a lot of different stuff here ...

<Fragment>
  <Component Id="AddConfigurationFilesFolder" ...>
  ...
  <!-- This component just serves as a bound point - see below -->
  ...
</Fragment>
```

So far so good.

Now, **`RemoveUpdatesAction.cs file`** that contains a custom action:

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult RemoveUpdatesAction(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            // Provide unique IDs
            int indexFile = 1;
            int indexDir = 1;

            // Begin work
            session.Log("Begin RemoveUpdatesAction");

            // Bind to the component that for sure will be uninstalled during UnInstall action
            // You can see this component mentioned above
            const string componentId = "AddConfigurationFilesFolder";

            // Get '..\{ProgramData}\MyApp' folder
            // This property (SETTINGSINSTALLFOLDER) is mentioned too
            string appDataFolder = session["SETTINGSINSTALLFOLDER"];

            // Populate RemoveFile table in MSI database with all files 
            // created in '..\{ProgramData}\MyApp\*.*' folder - pls see notes at the beginning
            if (!Directory.Exists(appDataFolder))
            {
              session.Log("End RemoveUpdatesAction");
              return ActionResult.Success;
            }

            foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(appDataFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                session.Log("Processing Subdirectory {0}", directory);
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory))
                {
                    session.Log("Processing file {0}", file);

                    string keyFile = string.Format("CLEANFILE_{0}", indexFile);

                    // Set values for columns in RemoveFile table:
                    // {1}: FileKey => just unique ID for the row
                    // {2}: Component_ => reference to a component existed in Component table
                    //      In our case it is already mentioned 'AddConfigurationFilesFolder' 
                    // {3}: FileName => localizable name of the file to be removed (with ext.)
                    // {4}: DirProperty => reference to a full dir path
                    // {5}: InstallMode => 3 means remove on Install/Remove stage
                    var fieldsForFiles = new object[] { keyFile, componentId, Path.GetFileName(file), directory, 3 };

                    // The following files will be processed:
                    // 1. '..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\tool.exe'
                    // 2. '..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\somelib.dll'
                    // 3. '..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\<UniqueFolderNameBasedOnGUID>\someliba.dll'
                    // 4. '..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\<UniqueFolderNameBasedOnGUID>\somelibb.dll'
                    InsertRecord(session, "RemoveFile", fieldsForFiles);

                    indexFile++;
                }

                string keyDir = string.Format("CLEANDIR_{0}", indexDir);

                // Empty quotes mean we we want to delete the folder itself
                var fieldsForDir = new object[] { keyDir, componentId, "", directory, 3 };

                // The following paths will be processed:
                // 1. '..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\'
                // 2. '..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\<UniqueFolderNameBasedOnGUID>\'
                InsertRecord(session, "RemoveFile", fieldsForDir);

                indexDir++;
            }

            session.Log("End RemoveUpdatesAction");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            session.Log("RemoveUpdatesAction EXCEPTION:" + exception.Message);
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
    }

    // Took completely from another SO question, but is accoring to MSDN docs
    private static void InsertRecord(Session session, string tableName, Object[] objects)
    {
        Database db = session.Database;
        string sqlInsertSring = db.Tables[tableName].SqlInsertString + " TEMPORARY";
        View view = db.OpenView(sqlInsertSring);
        view.Execute(new Record(objects));
        view.Close();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Condition for uninstall (`(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")`) I took from [here](http://alekdavis.blogspot.ru/2013/05/wix-woes-what-is-your-installer-doing.html).

This is pretty much all I done and after **Install/Uninstall** cycle I see in msi log file and in RemoveFile table (via enumerating the records) that all this entries are indeed inserted. 
**But the files and folders in the `..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\...` remains no matter what I do**.

Can anyone clarify what I'm doing wrong?

I believe the problem might be in how I defined **DirProperty** in the Custom Action class. I put a directory path there, but I know (used Orca) that in **Directory** table there is no record with the temp folder I discovered via `Directory.GetDirectories`.

So **RemoveFile** table is being populated with records that has invalid reference to **Directory** table (is that right?). I tried to add those discovered folders in **Directory** table manually but failed - each time I try to get reference to **Directory** table I got an exception. What is the right way to populate Directory table in MSI? Does it make sense to populate Directory table at all?

For example, if I need to put there the following paths:

1. `..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\`
2. `..\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\<UniqueFolderNameBasedOnGUID>\`

How can I do this?

Anyway, please, suggest anything - any advice, tips or comments will be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

**MSI uninstall log**:

```
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:427]: Doing action: RemoveUpdatesAction
....
MSI (s) (B4:4C) [05:28:39:450]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI7643.tmp,    Entrypoint:     RemoveUpdatesAction
....  
Action start 5:28:39: RemoveUpdatesAction.  
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI7643.tmp-\  
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319  
Calling custom action RemoveUpdatesAction!RemoveUpdatesAction.CustomActions.RemoveUpdatesAction  
Begin RemoveUpdatesAction  
Processing Subdirectory C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp  
Processing file C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\somelib.dll  
Processing file C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\tool.exe  
Processing Subdirectory C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\48574917-4351-4d4c-a36c-381f3ceb2e56  
Processing file C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\48574917-4351-4d4c-a36c-381f3ceb2e56\someliba.dll  
Processing file C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\48574917-4351-4d4c-a36c-381f3ceb2e56\somelibb.dll  
End RemoveUpdatesAction  
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:602]: Doing action: RemoveFiles  
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:602]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText   
Action ended 5:28:39: RemoveUpdatesAction. Return value 1.  
Action start 5:28:39: RemoveFiles.  
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:607]: Note: 1: 2727 2: C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp   
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:607]: Note: 1: 2727 2: C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\48574917-4351-4d4c-a36c-381f3ceb2e56   
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:607]: Counted 2 foreign folders to be removed.  
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:607]: Removing foreign folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Compass Mobile\  
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:607]: Removing foreign folder: C:\ProgramData\MyApp\  
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:607]: Doing action: RemoveFolders  
MSI (s) (B4:28) [05:28:39:607]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText   
Action ended 5:28:39: RemoveFiles. Return value 1.  
Action start 5:28:39: RemoveFolders.
```

As you can see I got **2727** error code. [That means](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx) for the following folders there are no records in Directory table:

> C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp
>   C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\48574917-4351-4d4c-a36c-381f3ceb2e56

So, maybe my suggestion is correct?

**References** for mentioned tags, MSI tables, etc.:

> [Creating WiX Custom Actions in C# and Passing Parameters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx)
>   [MSI DB's RemoveFile table description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371201(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   [MSI DB's Directory table description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   [RemoveFiles Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371199(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   [WiX CustomAction Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're not populating the RemoveFile table correctly. It would help if you logged that exact SQL insert string to see what's really there. I think you're getting error 2727 because the 4th thing in your insertion is supposed to be a directory property that refers to the directory table in the MSI file. It's not literally a directory name - it's supposed to be a key into the directory table of the MSI file - and as far as I can tell from your code it is an actual directory, not a value from the Directory table.

Comment: Yes, you right. I indeed put a real (not a Directory identifier) into RemoveFile table. I think too that this is wrong, but how do I suppose to set a valid ID (not path) for Directory if I do not know the name of it and can not update Directory table as well?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that you need to update the Directory table. I'd guess that there is already a directory in there related to the location of the files you want to remove. Or it's a standard Windows folder like AppDataFolder that you could add the Directory table without causing any issues.

Comment: Let me clarify. I have `C:\ProgramData\MyApp` and `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp` entries in Directory table. But how can I add an entry for the following folder: `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Temp\6889D79E-EA63-42C8-A81D-7AF62A2B1E4F`? I do not know the name of it - it is going to be known only in runtime - before new update procedure begins. And I need to delete all files in that directory later. Am I missing smth?

Comment: No, you don't have them in the Directory table :) You have an entry in the Directory table that refers to them.  Your DirProperty in your insertion string must refer to that Directory key. Similarly, I assume that AddConfigurationFilesFolder is actually a Component entry in the Component table.

Comment: You mean, the top-level directory that contains both - `\Temp` and `\Temp\{GUID}`? Yes, I do have one entry (`SETTINGSINSTALLFOLDER`). And I tried to point `DirProperty` to that entry for each subdir, but w/o any success. `AddConfigurationFilesFolder` is indeed a ComponentId defined within `SETTINGSINSTALLFOLDER` folder and has its entry in Component table.

Comment: It might be the top level directory, depending on what your Directory table looks like. It needs to be the containing directory such that if you add a file name then you'll get the actual full path to the file. Don't put the full path to the file in the Filename.